# Finding file structure in a drive?

Tags: file, dictionary

I was wondering if there was anyway to effectively write out in a readable formate the file structure of a drive. So what I mean by this is if it can write out a result simmilar to...

```
C:/
  File here 
  Another file here
     Sub file here
  Another file here
```

So sorta like that. I don't know what it is called but if there is something that does that then that would be great!! Even better if it was possable to do in batch (dosnt matter either way tho) Thanks :)

Comment: Ok ok I found out that it's called a tree :D haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the command prompt in windows. Write:

```
tree
```

if you want options write tree /?

Comment: yeah, its been around for a while and has "faded into oblivion". I remember using the tree command when I was young in the 80s...